# Scroll internal DIV

Tags: html, css

I have a DIV structure as following:

```
<DIV id="main">
   <DIV id="header">
   </DIV>
   <DIV id="inside">
   </DIV>
</DIV>
```

And this is the Layout

```
|________________|
|                |
|  |----------|  |
|  |  header  |  |
|  |          |  |
|  |----------|  |
|                |
|  |----------|  |
|  |  inside  |  |
|  |          |  |
|__|__________|__|
   |          |   
   |          |   
   |          |   
   |----------|
```

The **main** div has a fixed height of 300px and I setup the div as following in order to not show the extra content

```
#main{
   height: 300px;
   overflow: hidden;
}
```

The **header** div doesn't have any style because it's just one row with a `<SPAN>` inside.

The div **inside** actually is overflowing its content but I don't see the scroll-bar to scroll the content. I setup the div as following:

```
#inside{
   overflow-y:auto;
}
```

What happens is that the header should stay there and the inside div should display a vertical scrollbar if the content overflow.
How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are giving fixed height to parent tag then you must do something with inside tags as well.

give fix height, give calc height etc.

so here is the [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jqzZRr) to play around  for you with answer.

```css
#main{
  height: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#header
{
  width:100%;
  height:25px;
}
#inside{
  overflow:auto;
  height:275px;
}
```

```html
<DIV id="main">
  <DIV id="header">
    <span>title</span>
  </DIV>
  <DIV id="inside">
    dsfdsfds
    <br/>
    ff
    <br/>
    sdf
    <br/>
    dsf
    <br/>
    dsf
    <br/>
    ds
    <br/>
    fsd
    <br/>
    fsd
    <br/>
    fds
    <br/>
    feds
    <br/>
    rewr
    <br/>
    few
    <br/>
    re
    <br/>
    rf
    <br/>
    dsf
    <br/>
    dsf
    <br/>
    dsf
    <br/>
    ds
    <br/>
    fds
    <br/>
    fsd
    <br/>
    fds
    <br/>
    f<br/>
    dsf
    <br/>
    dsf
    <br/>
    d
  </DIV>
</DIV>
```

Comment: Understood, so I probably need to use Calc.

Comment: yes calc is good option for you. do some calculation minus from 300px as it is your parent tags height. like calc(300px - 95%);

Answer (score 0):

> **Try:**

```
#main{
   height: 300px;
   overflow: hidden;
}
#inside{   
    height: 300px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<pre><style>
#main{
   height: 300px;
   overflow-y: scroll;
}
</style>
</pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define height to the `inside div` to make it scrollable like this :

```
#inside{
 overflow-y:scroll; /* scrolls when content overflows */
 height: 100px;
}
```

With `overflow-y:scroll`, the content is clipped and a scrolling mechanism is provided. But the scroll will only be visible if you provide a `height` to the `div`. As soon as the content overflows the defined height scroll is shown.